# select either file or textarea data with ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to select either file or entered data. i need to validate that but i failed. it takes must be either file or text data only with button click. please help me to solve this problem thanks in advance. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g8Nz/693/)

i need if user entered both file and textarea text it shows error. user must select either file or textarea only. this is my requirement

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" >
  Upload file: <input type="file" id="file" /><br/><br/>
  Enter text: <textarea id="textarea" required></textarea>
  <br/><br/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submitForm = function(){
    alert("hi");
    var string1 = document.getElementById('file').value;
    var string2 =document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    if (string1 == string2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can't use required on both inputs if it's an either or condition.

Comment: i need if user entered both file and text it shows error. user must select either file or textarea only. this is my requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no how to get the filename with `ng-model` for it doesn't work with `type=file`.

To achieve what you want, you must create a directive, as seen in the link below:
https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

After that, you must assign the `file-model` directive to the input, telling which variable of the `$scope` will be two-way-binded with the value.

The textarea data could be achieved with ng-model.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g8Nz/719/)

Comment: thanks. but how to validate if user selects both file & textarea. i need to show alert..

Comment: i need if user selects only one not for both. i need to validate that manner

Comment: I've had updated the JSFiddle, please check. 
There's a directive `ng-disabled` with validations.

Comment: If it fills your needs, check the answer =)

Comment: Glad I could help! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use required on both inputs if it's an either or condition.

I created a codepen that should work for you here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdYBWp

Here's the code:

HTML

```
    <form name="form" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
        Upload file:
       <input type="file" id="file" ng-model="ctrl.file" />
     <br/>
     <br/> Enter text:
     <textarea id="textarea" ng-model="ctrl.text"></textarea>
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="ctrl.submitForm()">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

JavaScript
          angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', function() {

```
      var vm = this;
      vm.file = ""
      vm.text = ""

      vm.submitForm = function() {
      // angular doesn't update the model for input type="file"
      vm.file = document.getElementById('file').value;
      var retVal = false ;
      if (vm.file && ! vm.text) 
            {retVal = true}
      else if (vm.text && ! vm.file) 
          {retVal = true}
      else if (!vm.text && !vm.file) 
          {retVal = false}
      else if (vm.text && vm.file) 
            {retVal = false}

      if (!retVal) {
          alert("Please specify either a file or text, not both!")
      } else
            alert("ok")
      }
      });
```

You probably could combine all the ifs & else ifs into a single expression, but it wouldn't be very readable IMO.

Comment: What's not working? I tested all of the possible combinations in the codepen and they all work as I'd expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

once you click on file input then disable the textarea field and if u don't have any file to upload you can click on text area field and onClick of textarea disable file input

Comment: please expand on this answer by adding code examples, thank you